# Emulating functionality of python's inspect module in wsadmin

Tags: python, websphere, jython, wsadmin

I expected the inspect module would be integrated into wsadmin by default since it is part of jython 2.1, which is the jython version wsadmin seems to be using (2, 1, 0, 'final', 0) according to sys.version_info. I get this error "ImportError: no module named inspect"

I am trying to use inspect.isfunction() and inspect.getargspec() to allow a higher level perl script check that the command usage is correct and to call an arbitrary wsadmin jython function by name.

Is there any way I can emulate these functions behavior without inspect? 
Also, Why is inspect missing? It seems like it should be there...

Answer (score 0):

This will emulate inspect.isfunction():

```
import types;
isinstance(obj, types.FunctionType)
```

This will emulate inspect.getargspec():  (At least for my purposes)

```
# Gets list of arguments of function myFx
myFx.func_code.co_varnames[:myFx.func_code.co_argcount]

# Gets a list of the default values of myFx arguments
myFx.func_defaults
```